# Copying txt file to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy the text file from S3 to Redshift using the below command but getting the same error.

> **Error**:
>   Missing newline: Unexpected character 0xffffffe2 found at location 177
>
> copy table from 's3://abc_def/txt_006'
>   credentials '1234567890'
>   DELIMITER '|' 
>   NULL AS 'NULL'
>   NULL AS '' ;

The text file has No header and field delimiter is `|`.
I tried passing the parameters using: `ACCEPTINVCHARS`.

Redshift shows same error

> 1216 error code: invalid input line.

Can anyone provide how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your question appropriately.

Comment: Have you checked the contents at location 177? If you can provide a sample of data that causes the error, along with the table description, that could help us help you.

Comment: Try to open the file ( hexadecimal editor) and check what is in this location?

Answer (score 0):

Is your file in UTF8 format? if not convert it and try reloading.

Answer (score 0):

**I am Assuming path to the text file is correct. Also you generated the text file with some tool and uploaded to redshift manually**

I faced the same issue and the issue is with whitespaces .I recommend you to generate the text file by nulling and trimming the whitespaces .

your query should be **select RTRIM(LTRIM(NULLIF({columnname}, ''))),.., from {table}**. generate the output of this query into text file.

If you are using SQl Server, query out the table using **BCP.exe** by passing the above query with all the columns and functions

Then use the below copy command after uploading the txt file in S3

copy {table}
from 's3://{path}.txt' 
access_key_id '{value}'
secret_access_key '{value}' { you can alternatively use credentials as mentioned above }
delimiter '|' 
 COMPUPDATE ON
removequotes
acceptinvchars
emptyasnull 
trimblanks 
BLANKSASNULL 
FILLRECORD 
; 
commit; 

This solved my problem. Please let us know if you are facing anything else.